# sprite moves too fast after I unlimited the frame rate

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, frame-rate

I unlimited the frames per second in my game by doing.

```
graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false;
IsFixedTimeStep = false;
```

But now my sprite/player moves WAY faster then it did before. I don't know why it does this, and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) || keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
{
    position.Y -= spd;
}
if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) || keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
{
    position.X -= spd;
}
if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) || keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
{
    position.Y += spd;
}
if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D) || keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
{
    position.X += spd;
}
```

That is currently how I am getting the sprite to move. `spd = 4` at the moment. It worked perfectly fine, but now it seems as if it is moving like 2000 times faster. Just taping one of the keys takes him off screen.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: a compelling reason to write framerate independent code

Comment: @bkconrad: It is apparent the OP has never tried, maybe never heard of the concept.

Comment: -1 Please, try to complete and understand some basic tutorials before asking things like this. Also, a simple search would have provided the answer and other extra information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game loop in XNA is based around update and draw. Fixed time step also refers to update, so by setting that to false, you are telling update to be called as often as possible. As your code is in the update function, its being called more than the default, fixed 60 times per second.

rather than just using spd, change it to

```
spd * (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds / 16);
```

That will change it so that the spd is scaled by the elapsed time. The 16 is the number of milliseconds an update takes at 60 fps (approx) which is what your spd value is currently working at.

EDIT: For not part of Game.cs:

Have an update on the class you are interested in moving (Im going to call it Ship, but it could be anything you want)

```
class Ship
{
  public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
  {
    ...
    position.Y += spd * (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds / 16);
    ...
  }
  ..
}
```

Then in the Game.cs file:

```
public override Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
  myShip.Update(gameTime);
  ...
}
```

myShip being the variable for the class of the sprite you want to move. Note update is no longer overriding a base method, so the call to base.Update is also gone

Comment: I get the error.
Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.TimeSpan

Comment: Thats what I get for writing before I think! Sorry, it should be:
spd * (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds / 16);

Comment: Id also add that @KendallFrey solution is more elegant. You should define it in terms of seconds, not frames, but mine should work for the speed value you currently have. I would agree that it should be the distance per second if you write code like this from scratch

Comment: @Venatu now I am getting the error.
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
But that only happens after I run it then press the key.

Comment: @IanLundberg Im guessing gameTime is not what you have in your update definition as the argument name. Could you post the line where you override update?

Comment: @Venatu http://pastebin.com/fyqsbJEf That is my override update I removed gameTime from the arguments because I get an error. I would like to use it in a class, and not in the main Game.cs. Thanks!

Comment: @IanLundberg: Do you have a variable named `gameTime` somewhere? If so, you need to either rename it or rename the `GameTime` parameter of `Update`. Either way, you need to get a `GameTime` value from `Update`.

Comment: Re: Edit: That class would better be suited as a `GameComponent`.

Comment: I would agree but am trying to keep complexity down.

Comment: Right, but isn't using `GameComponent` the simplest way to do this? It automatically gets a GameTime without you needing to call it. I agree that it is best to avoid confusing people with new stuff, though.

Comment: @KendallFrey How would I add gameTime to the arguments of the Update override because whenever I try to add one it gives me the error.
'MyGame.Player.Update(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: Personnel preference to be honest, so a little biased!. I did use GameComponent when I needed code to be easily portable, but for sprites in one project I needed to be able to define the update/draw order and know for certain what it would be. For a case like this I thought it may be overkill

Comment: @IanLundberg remove the word override, like in the example above. There is no base Update in Player to override

Comment: @Ian: You definitely have the right idea in component-based programming. Let me point out the `GameComponent` class, which is designed to help you with that. Read up on it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent_members(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx

Comment: @Venatu When I remove override that key when pressed doesn't move the sprite at all. and Kendall I will look into it. thanks

Comment: @IanLundberg We may be speaking cross purposes here. The override keyword you remove is in the Player class, while the override keyword in the Game class should still be present. Is that the case?

Comment: @IanLundberg Using breakpoints, check that Player.Update is being called, and the value of position is changing. Other than that I have no immediate suggestion sorry, and have to be away for a while. I hope your problem is resolved, but if not Ill look again when I get back online. Best of luck!

Comment: @Venatu Okay, and just letting you know it doesn't get called.

Comment: @Venatu Okay I got it working. However when I use the code you gave me. It doesn't move at all. Before when I used the code you gave me if I just left spd the way it was it still wouldn't move. But now if I add the code you gave me it doesnt move at all, but if I leave spd the way it was before, it moves, but still very very fast. just thought I would let you know.

Comment: @IanLundberg That sounds odd. Could you post your Game.cs and player class please? Id like to fix this for my peace of mind as well as yours!

Comment: @Venatu I ended up fixing it. Turns out it WAS moving but very very slowly hardly even noticable. So I ended up just doing this.
`position.X += spd * ((float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 60);`
And now it works fine.

Comment: @IanLundberg Thats odd, I would have thought it would give exactly the same rate as your first attempt. Glad its now working for you!

Answer (score 4):

When you turn off a fixed timestep, you need to take the time delta into the calculation to have any control over movement. For example:

```
if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) || keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
{
    position.Y -= spd * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
}
...
```

In this case, you would set `spd` to the distance per *second*, not per *frame*.

Comment: What's the risk of integer wrap-around when multiplying `spd` by `TotalSeconds`?

Comment: @sarnold: None. You get a `double`.

Comment: @KendallFrey I get the error
'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
After I run it then press the Key.

Comment: @Ian: Use a debugger. Find out what is `null`. Then post it here.